Player A and B flip a coin alternatively till HT comes up. Player A goes first. Whoever flips the T wins. What is the probability that A wins?
This question might sound dumb but is quite literally breaking my mind. I'm questioning the symmetry of the problem. The traditional answer starts as such:
Let $P(A)$ be the probability that $A$ wins and likewise for $P(B)$. So $P(A) = 1 - P(B)$. Then $P(A) = 1/2P(A|H) + 1/2P(A|T)$. If $A$'s first toss is $T$, then $B$ essentially becomes the first to toss. So we have $P(A|T) = P(B) = 1 - P(A)$...
I am very confused with that last step. If we are to write that $P(A|T) = P(B)$ then shouldn't we have to define $A$ as the event where $A$ wins given that they flip first, and $B$ as the event where $B$ wins given that they flip first. In this definition clearly $P(A) = P(B)$. But do these probabilities need to add to one (i.e. $P(A)=P(B)=1/2$)? Furthermore, in this case it takes away from the original meaning of $P(A)$ and $P(B)$  as it no longer takes into account the fact that $A$ goes first and $B$ goes second. So I conclude that $A$ and $B$ can not be defined as such, but in that case $P(A|T) \neq P(B)$. Something feels circular.
Another way I tried thinking about it is if $A$ first flips a $T$, then $B$ is now in the position where $A$ originally was. Assuming our original definition of the events $A$ and $B$ where $A$ is the event that player $A$ wins and $B$ is the event where player $B$ wins (I keep in mind that $B$ goes after $A$). But I can't necessarily say that $P(A|T) = P(B)$ because the events $A$ and $B$ are not equal since player $A$ goes first.
I must've gone wrong somewhere with my logic. Why is it that $P(A|T) = P(B)$? Can someone please enlighten me with the use of symmetry here?

This is not at all trivial. One would guess 1/2 , but such exercises often lead to a surprising result.

It might help to start with the easier problem : Suppose H occured. Then , the player tossing T first , wins. In this case , if we denote $p$ the probability that the player starting wins , then the second player has a probability $\frac{p}{2}$ to win. This gives us $p=\frac{2}{3}$. This is also the probability that player A tosses the first H. This should allow to compute every case.

@Peter how did you deduce that the second player has a probability p/2?

Well, the first player must toss $H$ and then , the second player becomes the first player.

@Peter ah I see. The first player has a half chance of flipping heads, so the second player has $1/2 \times p = p/2$ probability of winning. Could you then help me explain the error in my logic in seeing that $P(A|T) = P(B)$?

More likely should be $\mathbb{P}[B|T]=\mathbb{P}[A]$, because after $A$ gives $T$, its now $B$'s turn.

The probability that player $A$ tosses the first H and that player A wins is $\frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{3}=\frac{2}{9}$. The probability that player $B$ tosses the first H and that player $A$ wins is $\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{2}{3}=\frac{2}{9}$. Hence , the probability for $A$ to win is $\frac{4}{9}$.

P(A|T)=P(current player eventually wins given that he tosses a T in this turn) = P(previous player eventually wins given that they tossed a T in their turn) = P(current player eventually loses given that previous player tossed T in their turn) = P(first player eventually loses a new game) = P(second player eventually wins a new game) = P(B).  The hard part is the second equality, which is the same moment in time of the game, but described from the point of view of the other player.

@JaapScherphuis I think the key idea you brought is that we are looking at it from a different point of view, but we are at the same moment in the time of the game. In this case, it makes more intuitive sense that the probabilities are equal as they just two ways of describing the same situation. My brain hurts less now. Thank you :)

@Peter Why do you multiply $\frac{2}{3}$ by $\frac{1}{3}$. Where did you get the $\frac{1}{3}$ from?

I think you just need to be clear about the notation.  Perhaps say:

$P(A)$ as the probability at the start that the first player wins overall, and similarly $P(B)$ as the probability at the start that the second player wins overall with $$P(B)=1-P(A)$$
$P(A \mid H)$ as the probability after the first flip if it was Heads that the initially first player wins overall, and similarly $P(B \mid H)$ with $$P(B \mid H)=1-P(A \mid H)$$
$P(A \mid T)$ as the probability after the first flip if it was Tails that the initially first player wins overall, and similarly $P(B \mid T)$ with $$P(B \mid T)=1-P(A \mid T)$$

It then seems easy to say (since the first flip has an outcome) $$P(A) = \frac12 P(A \mid H)+\frac12 P(A \mid T)$$ and (since the first flip being Tails makes no progress towards the target but switches the flipper)  $$P(A \mid T)= P(B)$$ and not much harder to say (since if the first flip is heads, the next Tails will win) $$P(B \mid H) =\frac12+\frac12 P(A \mid H).$$
You now have six equations in six unknowns.

You're getting confused by the definition of $B$, so let's just not define it. Instead have $A$ be the event that player $A$ wins (and they are the player flipping first). Let $H$ be the event of player $A$'s first flip being heads. Then
$$P[A] = \frac12P[A|H] + \frac12P[A|H^c].$$
Now if $A$ flips tails then effectively $B$ becomes the first flipper, and so the probability that $A$ wins from here is equal to the probability that $A$ would lose at the start of the game:
$$P[A|H^c] = 1-P[A].$$
And if $A$ flips heads, then either $B$ flips tails in which case $A$ loses, or $B$ flips heads in which case $A$'s probability of winning is now equal to "$A$'s probability of losing immediately after $A$ flips a head".
$$P[A|H] = \frac12\cdot0+\frac12(1-P[A|H]).$$
Solve to get $P[A|H] = \frac13$. So
$$P[A] = \frac16 + \frac12(1-P[A]).$$
So $P[A] = \frac49$.

And to add some intuition for the result, it makes sense that A has a lower than half probability of winning because they get the first flip, the only flip which can never win the game.

I do not understand this logic "or $B$ flips heads in which case $A$'s probability of winning is now equal to $A$'s probability of losing immediately after they flip a head".

@LeoLiang After $B$ flips heads, $A$ has $p$ probability of winning, say. This must be equal to the probability of $B$ winning after $A$ flips heads. And $B$ winning is equivalent to $A$ losing. By "they" I meant $A$, I'll clarify that.

Let $p_1$ be the probability that the current player wins, given that the other player just tossed $H$.
Then the current player either gets $T$ and wins, or gets $H$ and the roles are reversed. Thus
$$ p_1 = \frac12 + \frac12(1-p_1).$$
From this, $$ p_1=\frac23.$$
Let $p_2$ be the probability that the current player wins, given that the other player just tossed $T$ (without winning). This time, we get
$$ p_2 = \frac12(1-p_2)+\frac12(1-p_1)$$
because the current player either tosses $T$ and the roles are reversed, or tosses $H$  and the other player wins with $p_1$.
Finally, the desired probaility that $A$ wins from start, is also $p_2$ (why?).

I am confused as to what you are proving in this case.

Okay so thanks to @JaapJaapScherphuis I think the key to recognizing the symmetry in this problem is not in any mathematical representation, but rather looking at a moment in time from two perspectives.
After player $A$ flips a tails, at this instant in the game, we can describe it two ways from two perspectives. From player $A$'s point of view, this moment can be described as $P(A|T)$. But from player $B$'s perspective, this moment can be described as $P(B)$. Now since we have two ways of describing the same moment in the game, they must be equivalent. This answers my question of how the two events have a one-to-one correspondence.
Let me know if ya'll think this makes sense too. Please add to my explanation to make it more precise as my choice of words may be slightly off.
